# How do I find all word combinations that add up to a certain length?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math

I need a little help with coming up with an algorithm to traverse through a sorted word array and finding all the possible combinations that add up to a certain length. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: I meant to say any number of words that adds up to the length. Sorry about that.

Comment: You shouldn't change your question altogether when there are answers. You could have written "edit: bla bla bla", or posted another question...

Comment: @paulpaul1076 Got it, I'll remember that next time. Sorry, still a bit new to this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Gotcha, also make your question a question, it needs to have a question mark at the end, and not look like a title. This is one of the basic recommendations that you can read, if you google "how to ask a question on stackoverflow".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>0) Get the lengths into a separate array.</strike>

1) Sort that array.

2) Use the algorithm for the "two sum" problem to find the lengths.

How the two sum algorithm works:

Suppose you want to find a pair of words that add up to a certain length.

You need 2 for loops.

Say that length is x.

0) The outer loop linearly traverses the entire array.

1) The inner loop binary searches x - a[i].length, where x is the length of 2 strings.

To get only distinct pairs, store the pairs you have found in a hash set.

**EDIT:**
Since you then changed your question to "any number of words". Then you can use the following algorithm. I am not sure what language you use. But usually, to get all subsets from a set you need to do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1 << n; ++i)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
  {
     if(i >> j & 1)
     {
         // concatenate strings here
         // add them to a list
     }
  }
  if(concatenatedStr.length == k)
  {
      // store those strings in a hash set
  }
}
```

Since int is a 32 bit number for arbitrary number of elements you can use something like BigInteger. However, to be honest, I don't think you want to do this for anything bigger than 32 elements, because the algorithm itself is O(2^n + whatever else we do inside those loops).

How does this work?

Well, there are 2^n subsets in a set of n elements, and when you do 1 << n, it moves 1 n positions to the left, so that it's located at (n+1)'th position, followed by all zeros.

1 << n - 1 gives you n 1's. And if you do i = 0; i <= 1 << n - 1 (or i = 0; i < 1 << n) you basically generate all subsets, because binary numbers are incremented as follows:

0

1

10

11

100

101

110

etc...

So you basically generate all subsets... As you generate them you can do whatever you want with them, including finding the subsets whose sum of lengths are equal to k, just as I showed in that algorithm.

Comment: Generating all subsets may be infeasible, while generating only the subsets of small lengths is feasible. For example, suppose all words have length 4, there are 100 words, and we want the total length to be 12. The number of combinations of length 12 is 161,700 while the number of all subsets is 1,267,650,600,228,229,401,496,703,205,376.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is sorted by length, you can keep two pairs of indexes, one to traverse from the low end (shortest words) and one to traverse from the high end.

Find a range of words of the same length.

Find a range of words at the high end that also have the same length, and of which the length, when summed with the low range word length, gives you the desired length.

Then combine every word from the first range with every word of the second range.

Comment: SO answer scores are so funny sometimes - you should have gotten more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with dynamic programming. Let a[i,j] be a list of the ways to have a combination of the first i words with total length j. Let L be the length of the i+1st word. Then a[i+1,j] = a[i,j]+everything in a[i,j-L] with word i+1 appended. (In case you want just the count, you can compute that as b[i+1,j] = b[i,j]+b[i,j-L]. Computing just the counts takes O(|dictionary|*target length) steps this way.)

One problem with this is that you might compute many large lists that can't contribute to the final list. For example, suppose there are a few words of length 5, and lots of words of length 6, and you have a total length of 25. These will only come from combinations of words of length 5. The effort creating combinations of length 18 and 24 is wasted. To avoid computing long lists that don't contribute to the final answer, first compute a boolean c[i,j] which indicates whether you can reach the target if after using some of the first i words, the length of your combination is j. You can use dynamic programming again, starting with i=target and working down to i=0. After you compute the array c[i,j], compute the array of lists a[i,j] only if c[i,j] is true, and ignore a[i,j] if c[i,j] is false.